# Best method to backup user data(database) to online storage

Tags: android, database-backups

Currently, I was developing an android application that is creating an SQLite database inside the app. That database store user entered data. Now I need to give a method to auto backup that database to some online storage and when the user changes the device or reinstall the app restore that database back. If anyone can suggest me the best way to do that I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You have mainly two option:

1. Use the google drive storage of the user of you app. [Here's](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/appfolder) how to get started. The advantage of using this solution is that you don't have to pay anything, but you don't have so much control on that data.
2. Use cloud services as Google Cloud Platform, Microsoft Azure, AWS, etc. Here you have to pay some money depending on connections, amount of storage, amount of user, other services, etc, but you have good control of the data.

If you choose the second way I suggest you to take a look to firebase. It is based on Google cloud platform but it has a good range of functions, it is really easy to implement in your app and it is really good for testing before your first release (because the threshold between free and paid version is high)

Comment: Hello sir, thank you for answering. Can you please explain how can i achieve that. I like to use google drive. But i have no idea where to start and what classes should i create or how the classes shoul manage. Currently i have integrated google sign in option as signin activity. I'd like to give a data synchronize button in my app settings also. If you can please explain how the classes should define and whats need to be done, or a complete tutorial if available. Thank you.